# Solvable radical and closed Lie subgroups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds, normal-subgroups, topological-groups

I have the following situation: let $\mathfrak{g}$ be an $n-$dimensional real Lie algebra of the connected Lie group $G$ and let $\mathfrak{r}(\mathfrak{g})$ be the solvable radical of $\mathfrak{g}$. If I consider $R = \langle \hbox{exp}{(\mathfrak{r}(\mathfrak{g}))}\rangle$, then is $R$ a closed subgroup of $G$?

My idea was to prove that $clR$ is the maximal solvable Lie subgroup of $G$, but I got nowhere.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: assume it is not closed, then study the closure (check solvability and normality).

Comment: I think I get it: It is not hard to prove by induction that $(cl R)^k \subset cl(R^k)$. By solvability, there is a $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $R^{k_0} = \{1\}$, then $(cl R)^{k_0} \subset (clR^{k_0}) = \{1\}$. Therefore $(cl R)^{k_0} = \{1\}$. The set $(cl R)$ is already a normal subgroup (closure of normal subgroup). Hence $R$ and $clR$ share the same Lie algebra, implying that $R$ is closed by uniqueness.

Comment: One can also reason in the following way. If $R$ is a maximal normal connected solvable subgroup of the Lie group $G$, then it corresponds to a solvable ideal in the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. And so on.